# Cron Job not working using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I am trying to learn Cron Job and whenever gem.
In my app i have created a rake task.

```
require 'rubygems'

namespace :cron_job do
  desc "To Check Users Inactivity"
  task user_inactivity: :environment do
    p "Inactive Users..."
  end
end
```

and in schedule.rb i have wrote like this

```
every 1.minute do
  rake "cron_job:user_inactivity", environment: "development"
end
```

and in my terminal i wrote two commands

```
 whenever --update-crontab
```

and then

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cron restart
```

but nothing is happening after 1 minute.
I checked my console for p messages and nothing happens. Do i miss something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output won't show in your console.

You have to set the output log path by:

```
set :output, "/path/to/my/cron_log.log"
```

Then check the log.

Comment: @NidhinSG Where you want. And the code should put in `schedule.rb`, read the comments of that file.

Comment: should i give the Project path or complete path for log file

Comment: @NidhinSG If you want to put in the log directory in the Project, just use `set :output, 'log/cron_log.log'`